# Create variable based on counts of groups and sub groups in data table

Tags: r, count, group-by, data.table

I have many student records. I need to create two new variable. One should display the count of `Unitcode` (ie enrolments) for each `student_ID` for each `Year`.

One should display the count of `Fail` (ie Grade=='Fail') for each `student_ID` for each `Year`. See the example of records for three students below:

```
   student_ID=c(rep("1001",8),rep("1002",3),rep("1005",11))
   Year=c(rep(2011,4),rep(2012,4),2011,2012,2013,rep(2011,4),rep(2012,3),rep(2013,4))
   Grade=c(rep("Fail",2),rep("Pass",3),rep("Fail",3),rep("Pass",7),rep("Fail",2),rep("Pass",5))
   Unitcode<-c(1201:1222)
   record<-data.table(student_ID, Year, Grade, Unitcode)
```

If someone could assist with counting new variables that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RichardScriven Why did you delete the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar option using `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
record %>%
     group_by(student_ID, Year) %>%
     summarise(unitcodes=n(), fails=sum(Grade=='Fail'))
```